# How can I set the value of textbox to "0" if blank or empty?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, logic

I'm trying to have a textbox, which if blank or empty, will have the number zero inserted into it once a button is clicked. So far I've been trying this code, below, to no avail. The code below is for the `button_click` method. What am I missing?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    textBox2.Text = "0";                
}
```

Comment: You have the logic inversed. You are saying "if the text is __not__ null or empty set it to "0""

Comment: why don't you do this using javascript?

Comment: Is this in WinForms or WPF? You can easily do a DataTrigger in WPF to reduce code-behind

Comment: ^ !string.IsNullOrEmpty equates to IsNotNullOrEmpty

Comment: @selectDistinct: JavaScript? In WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `!`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    textBox2.Text = "0";                
}
```

`!` will negate the logical expression. It means `not` of something

so `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)` is true when string is (not empty) and (not null).

Comment: This helped so much! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "!".  You want to change the text when the string *is* null or empty.

Comment: Perfect! This helped so much! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!` before `string.IsNull`...

`!` is the same as having `!=` (not equals)

Answer (score -1):

Simply add a if-statment into a TextChanged event of textbox to do the checking...

No idea why you need a button click event...